# Добавление изображений к меткам

Tags: предложение

На enSO есть изображения меток например [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) имеет соответственный значок андроида.

Для чего спросите? Например чтобы на ваш вопрос ответили быстрее и не пропустили. Очень часто (я думаю не только у меня) пропускаю некоторые вопросы, причина тому плохое зрение. НО Видя значок я сразу понимаю о чем идет речь.

Comment: Это не просто значки, но ещё и [индикация спонсорства](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/318749) компанией, стоящей за меткой. И кроме как на enSO программа спонсорства пока нигде не сущестует, в т. ч. у нас.

Comment: ого даже так...

Comment: @D-side, почему не ответ? Негоже отвечать в комментах. Очень интересно, надо себе такое сделать.

Comment: @Other для моего стандарта ответов это недостаточно подробно. Или мне попросту лень. Выберите для себя наиболее правдоподобное объяснение :)

Comment: @Other потому что дубликат

Comment: @D-side, но это уже ответ. Могли бы дописать или попросить дописать за Вас.

Comment: @alexolut, яжнезнал.